# How to search for cells with the same column value in google sheets using script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a google sheet with my first column containing timestamps, the second column contains ID's

```
12/19/2019 1:11:19      1234
12/21/2020 0:16:13      2345
12/22/2020 23:50:09     1234
```

I want to loop through the columns of ID's for each row and see if there is a duplicate, so something like

```
for(var i = 1; i <= sheetLength;i++){
   //sheet variable is named sheet1 
   var id = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
   for(var j = 0; j <= sheetLength;j++){
     var idArray[j].setValue(id);
   }
}
```

From what I understand this puts all the ids in a dynamic array, how can I compare the next id in the row with the array to see if there is a duplicate or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Searching for same values**

This function searches all cells that are in the datarange and identifies the values that are the same and what ranges they are in.  I just tested with simple headers and numbers.

```
 function findCellsWithSameValue() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet234');
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet235');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var v=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var uObj={uA:[]};
  for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<v[i].length;j++) {
      var idx=uObj.uA.indexOf(v[i][j]);
      if(idx==-1) {
        uObj.uA.push(v[i][j])
        uObj[v[i][j]]=[];
        uObj[v[i][j]].push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation());
      }else{
        uObj[v[i][j]].push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation());
      }
    }
  }
  osh.clearContents();
  osh.appendRow(['Value','Ranges']);
  uObj.uA.forEach(function(v) {
    //eliminate unique values
    if(uObj[v].length>1) {
      osh.appendRow([v,uObj[v].join(', ')]);
    }
  })
}
```

This is the output for your data:

[image]